# Cumbersome Ord implementation for a custom data type

Tags: haskell

I've created a data type in Haskell:

```
type Name = String
data ModelNode = NodeAttribute Name | 
                 NodeRelation (Name,Name) |
                 NodeConstraint Name |
                 NodeKPI Name
```

And I need this type to be an instance of `Ord`. The implementation I came up with is:

```
instance Ord ModelNodeKind where
    compare (NodeAttribute n)  (NodeAttribute n') = compare n n'
    compare (NodeAttribute _)  _                  = LT
    compare _                  (NodeAttribute _)  = GT
    compare (NodeRelation n)   (NodeRelation n')  = compare n n'
    compare (NodeRelation _)   _                  = LT
    compare _                  (NodeRelation _)   = GT
    compare (NodeConstraint n) (NodeConstraint n')= compare n n'
    compare (NodeConstraint _) _                  = LT
    compare _                  (NodeConstraint _) = GT
    compare (NodeKPI n)        (NodeKPI n')       = compare n n'
```

Which looks a bit cumbersome to me in the elegant and concise Haskell world. Is there any trick/syntax rule to make it simpler? Or should I redesign my data type to something like:

```
data ModelNodeType = NodeAttribute | NodeRelation | NodeConstraint | NodeKPI
data ModelNode = ModelNode ModelNodeType Name Maybe Name
```

which is, after all, not semantically correct. Or

```
data ModelNodeTypeSingle = NodeAttribute | NodeConstraint | NodeKPI
data ModelNode = ModelNode ModelNodeTypeSingle Name | 
                 ModelNodeRelation (Name,Name)
```

which simplifies the implementation of `Ord`, but the data type itself becomes less readable?

Comment: As an unrelated note, you probably shouldn't be storing a pair in the `NodeRelation` constructor.  Unless you explicitly want the extra possibility of a bottom value, that constructor should be declared as `NodeRelation Name Name`.

Comment: For what it's worth, the pattern you've used is quite a natural one for manually implementing `Ord`, though in this particular case you may as well use `deriving`.

Comment: @Carl: Oh, yes, I agree. It just came naturally from the knowledge domain, but should better be changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your `Ord` instance is equivalent to the derivable one. Just do

```
data ModelNode = NodeAttribute Name | 
                 NodeRelation (Name,Name) |
                 NodeConstraint Name |
                 NodeKPI Name
  deriving (Eq,Ord)
```